# Sendgrid - Sending mails to multiple email recipients stored in a variable in Python

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send an email using SendGrid API in Python.

The below code works well however I am trying to have emails sent to a list of recipients that are stored in a variable `user_list`

```
message = Mail(
from_email=('mail@mail.com'),
to_emails= (user_list),
subject= 'subject,
html_content = 'content')
```

For example if `user_list` has three emails stored like `mail1@mail.com`, `mail2@mail.com`, `mail3@mail.com` only `mail1@mail.com` receives the email while the other recipients do not receive the email.

I see only the first email in the variable receives the email and the other emails do not receive the mail.

Comment: remove the inner brackets and try once.

Comment: @VikasP I did try that as well but did not help..

Comment: then you might have to use Personalizations